# How to loop through a file folder to run script for each item in folder?

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have a script that takes a sample from an excel file and spits back out that sample as a csv. How would one go about looping through a file folder with multiple excel files to avoid the task of changing the file for every run of the script? I believe I can use glob, but that appears to merely merge all the excel files together.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

root_dir = r"C:\Users\bryanmccormack\Desktop\Test_Folder\*.xlsx"
excel_files = glob.glob(root_dir, recursive=True)

for xls in excel_files:
    df_excel = pd.read_excel(xls)
    df_excel = df_excel.loc[(df_excel['Track Item']=='Y')]

def sample_per(df_excel):
    if len(df_excel) <= 10000:
        return df_excel.sample(frac=0.05)
    elif len(df_excel) >= 15000:
        return df_excel.sample(frac=0.03)
    else:
        return df_excel.sample(frac=0.01)

final = sample_per(xls)

df_excel.loc[df_excel['Retailer Item ID'].isin(final['Retailer Item ID']), 'Track Item'] = 'Audit'

df_excel.to_csv('Testicle.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: _but it doesn't work_ What happens?

Answer (score 0):

This returns a list of all files in a directory that you can iterate on:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join

def retrieve_file_paths(dirName):       #Declare the function to return all file paths of the particular directory
    filepaths = []                      #setup file paths variable
    for root, directories, files in walk(dirName):   #Read all directory, subdirectories and file lists
        for filename in files:
            filepath = join(root, filename)     #Create the full filepath by using os module.
            filepaths.append(filepath)

    return filepaths      #return all paths
```

at the end it should look something on this line:

```
import pandas as pd
from os import walk
from os.path import join

dirName = "/your/dir"

def sample_per(df2):
    if len(df2) <= 10000:
        return df2.sample(frac=0.05)
    elif len(df2) >= 15000:
        return df2.sample(frac=0.03)
    else:
        return df2.sample(frac=0.01)


def retrieve_file_paths(dirName):       #Declare the function to return all file paths of the particular directory
    filepaths = []                      #setup file paths variable
    for root, directories, files in walk(dirName):   #Read all directory, subdirectories and file lists
        for filename in files:
            filepath = join(root, filename)     #Create the full filepath by using os module.
            filepaths.append(filepath)

    return filepaths      #return all paths

def main():
    global dirName
    for filepath in retrieve_file_paths(dirName):
        df = pd.read_excel(r+filepath)
        df2 = df.loc[(df['Track Item']=='Y')]
        final = sample_per(df2)
        df.loc[df['Retailer Item ID'].isin(final['Retailer Item ID']), 'Track Item'] = 'Audit'
        df.to_csv('Test.csv',index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This works, but I'm getting an error about how str has no attibute "sample," which is strange becasue df_new is a dataframe.

Comment: @Tyrone_Slothrop i am not that familiar with this library but have you checked what df.loc[(df['Track Item']=='Y')] is returning? from your error it seems it's returning a simple string. If you print df2 what happes?

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track but using pd.concat() was 'responsible for merging your excel files. This snippet should help you:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# use regex style to get all files with xlsx extension
root_dir = r"excel/*.xlsx"
# this call of glob only gives xlsx files in the root_dir
excel_files = glob.glob(root_dir)

# iterate over the files
for xls in excel_files:
    # read
    df_excel = pd.read_excel(xls)
    # manipulate as you wish here
    df_new = df_excel.sample(frac=0.1)
    # store
    df_new.to_csv(xls.replace("xlsx", "csv"))
```

Note you can also pass *recursive=True* in the glob call which gives you (from python 3+ I believe) all excel files from the subdirectories.